# While Creating a extension function, the division in value is not supporting

Tags: c#

```
 public static class Helpers
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Game> AddRatingToGame(this IEnumerable<Game> games)
        {
            foreach(var game in games)
            {
            //game.rating = game.rating / 2f;           // division  is not working 
            game.rating = game.rating * 2f;
            game.name = $" {game.name} - {game.rating}";
            }
            return games;
        }
    }
```

this is the code for the extension function "AddRatingToGame"
Here i am trying to divide the rating by 2

```
//providing the random values to the player 
        var suggestedGames = gameList.Where(g => g.rating > 8f).OrderBy(g => _random.Next()).Take(3).AddRatingToGame();
        // takes 3 random values with 8.0 above rating
        Console.WriteLine("\nsuggested games:");

        foreach(var game in suggestedGames)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(game.name);   
        }
```

this is the main calling code.

suggested games:
Inside - 18
Townscrapper - 17
LittleNightmares - 19

This is result when multiplying with 2f

suggested games:

And this is the result when dividing the number .

The Class Game:

```
public class Game
    {
        public string name;
        public float rating;
        public Game(string Name,float rating)
        {
            this.name = Name;
            this.rating = rating;
        }
    }
```

I hope the question is clear, hoping some help:

I tried to divide the number, but now supporting.

Comment: LINQ uses deferred execution, so your `AddRatingToGame` is modifying the enumerable before it finishes running. Add a `ToList()` to force conversion to a list before modifying the results. `var suggestedGames = gameList.Where(g => g.rating > 8f).OrderBy(g => _random.Next()).Take(3).ToList().AddRatingToGame();` https://www.ideone.com/Mkde84

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is not to use an extension class and do the equation in a LINQ Select like the following

```
    Func<Game, Game> AddRatingToGame = (game) =>
    {
        game.Rating = game.Rating / 2f;
        game.Name = $" {game.Name} - {game.Rating}";
        return game;
    };

    //providing the random values to the player 
    var suggestedGames = gameList.Where(g => g.Rating > 8f).Select(AddRatingToGame);
```

Comment: The AddRatingToGame Func could be made static and put in a helper class if you want to reuse elsewhere